# Iochroma "Princess" leaf spots cause?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves

I have an *Iochroma* "Princess" plant that's developed sort-of mustard-yellow spots on its leaves (see photo).

[image]

Other than that, it seems to be doing very well (it's grown quite a bit since I planted it and, aside from the spots, seems healthy). I've looked *really* closely and there don't seem to be any tiny insects on the plant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be [Thrip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrips) damage. Thrips are very active fliers and can travel long distances on the wind, do their damage and move on. They make puncture marks on leaves which immediately are not very visible but later when the marks are numerous and result in dead discoloured cells the damage is suddenly apparent. Thrips are known to be a pest on Iochroma. You may need magnification to see if any eggs have been laid. Home gardeners can think in terms of insecticidal soap for control.

Comment: I've just sprayed some neem oil to see if that helps. I assume I'll have to do repeated applications.